# Bash if filename exists

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that I call from another script with a specific filename as second argument.

```
script1 </var/tmp/outputfile>
```

within script1, I want to add a logic to find if the filename after /var/tmp is 'outputfile' if, yes I need to add some logic, if not other logic.

Following code is not working in the script1.sh.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Invalid usage"
    echo "Usage: $0 <logfile>"
    exit 1
fi


if [[ $1 == *"outputfile" ]]; then        
    echo "Found it"
else    
    echo "Search fail"
fi
```

Note that input always includes the full path where the file is generated. I just need to search for the filename that is at the end of the input string ($1). I tried many ways. It is not working in the script.

If I try similar logic directly in the shell it is working fine. Can someone tell me what should I add in the script.

```
[root@mgmt:~]$echo $file
/var/tmp/output
[root@mgmt:~]$if [[ $file == *"output" ]] ; then echo "ok";  else echo "fail";fi
ok
```

Comment: are you sure, you are using `bash` not `sh` ? `[[ ... ]]` are `bash` specific. Try `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script instead of `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: yeah sorry it's not bash. it is /bin/sh. I tried without [[ but even that doesn't seem to work in the script.

Comment: Are you attempting to determine if the file exists (as stated in the title) or to find if the name specified by the user ends with `outputfile` (as indicated by your script)?  Those are two very different tasks.

Comment: I am attempting to find if the name specified in $1 ends with 'outputfile'. No need to check if file exists.

Comment: If you have to use `sh`, use a `case` statement

Comment: What's wrong with `if [ "$1" = "/var/tmp/outputfile" ]; then …; else …; fi`?  Or do you mean you want `if [ "$(basename "$1")" = "outputfile" ]; then …; else …; fi`?

Comment: note that you use `outputfile` in the script and `output` in your shell

Comment: Yes. the shell program was just for experiment.

Comment: Thanks Johathan.. basename logic worked.. completely forgot about it.. Otherthing that worked is  input=$(echo ${1##*/})                  
           echo $input   (this is extracting the file name correctly.